# C - why is arr[0] showing as 32767

Tags: c, arrays

Following is just one section on one code.
t is test case number and then i have integer n for each t.
i want to break integer to digits and store in array and then print each element of array.

input

```
1
45
```

expected output

```
5
4
```

actual output

```
32767
0
```

code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
int t,n,n1,tmp,in,len,j;
scanf("%d",&t);
while(t--)
    {
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int arr[]={};
    n1=n;
    in=0;
    len=0;
    while(n1>0)
        {
        tmp=n1%10;
        arr[in]=tmp;
        len++;
        n1=n1/10;
        in++;
        }
    for(j=0;j<len;j++)
        {
        printf("%d\n",arr[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `int arr[]={};` here, what do you expect the size of `arr` to be?

Comment: I dont know, it depends on input, if it is 12345, then size will be 5.

Comment: But C doesn't work that way. Arrays don't grow as needed, `int arr[]={};` is illegal.

Comment: ok, i used int arr[100]={} and it worked. But wont it occupy space for 100 integers whereas i actually used only 2.

Comment: @user3388005 and since even Windows has 1MB of stack space (not to mention better OSes like Linux, where it can be as big as 8 MB by default), you don't really have to care about 400 (or so) bytes.

Comment: those are default stack sizes, you can make it as big as you like (well, maybe not more than 2GB on 32bit)

Comment: @MattMcNabb that's why I wrote *"by default"…*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your definition of `int arr[]={};` which creates an empty array without space for storage. You are better off always defining a maximum array size, unless dynamically allocating. Fixing that issue (along with initializing all values) takes care of the issue.

The following is just one approach to correcting the issue. It defines a maximum number of array elements `MAXVALUES` of `128`. It also adds prompts to orient the user to the data requested, **and** prevents the trailing `newline` from your first use of `scanf` from being read as the input for `'n'`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXVALUES 128

int main () {

    int t = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int n1 = 0;
    int tmp = 0;
    int in = 0;
    int len = 0;
    int j = 0;

    printf ("\n Enter the number of numbers to convert: ");
    scanf ("%d%*c", &t);

    while (t--) {

        printf ("\n Enter the number 'n' : ");
        scanf ("%d%*c", &n);

        int arr[MAXVALUES] = {0};

        in = 0;
        len = 0;
        n1 = n;

        while (n1 > 0) {
            tmp = n1 % 10;
            arr[in] = tmp;
            len++;
            n1 = n1 / 10;
            in++;
        }

        for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            printf ("%d\n", arr[j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/arrayval

Enter the number of numbers to convert: 2

Enter the number 'n' : 12345
5
4
3
2
1

Enter the number 'n' : 56789
9
8
7
6
5
```

---

**Dynamically Allocate `arr` based on digits in `n`**

You can dynamically allocate `arr` to prevent having `#define` allocate more space than needed (this is kinda like using a sledge-hammer to swat a fly here). It just takes a little more work. Specifically, it takes knowing how many digits are in `n` before you allocate `arr` so you can allocate no more memory than needed. Here, the number of digits in `n` is calculated by the function `szitoa` and then `arr` is allocated. This is one approach to that type solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

/* determine number of chars required for string of int i,
does NOT include space for null char (like strlen) */
size_t
szitoa (int val)
{
    int it = 0;
    int sz = (val > 0) ? 0 : 1;   /* provide space of '-' */
    val = (val > 0) ? val : -val; /* absolute value */

    for (it = 1; it < INT_MAX; it*=10) {
        sz++;
        if (val >= it && val < (it*10))
            break;
    }

    return sz;
}

int main () {

    int t = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int n1 = 0;
    int tmp = 0;
    int in = 0;
    int len = 0;
    int j = 0;

    printf ("\n Enter the number of numbers to covert: ");
    scanf ("%d%*c", &t);

    while (t--) {

        printf ("\n Enter the number 'n' : ");
        scanf ("%d%*c", &n);

        /* dynamically allocate arr and validate */
        int *arr = calloc (szitoa (n), sizeof (int));
        if (!arr) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: arr allocation failed\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        in = 0;
        len = 0;
        n1 = n;

        while (n1 > 0) {
            tmp = n1 % 10;
            arr[in] = tmp;
            len++;
            n1 = n1 / 10;
            in++;
        }

        for (j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            printf ("%d\n", arr[j]);
        }

        if (arr) free (arr);           /* free memory allocated to arr */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int arr[]={};` is illegal in Standard C ; brace-enclosed initializer lists must have at least one initializer. (gcc has an extension that this declares a zero-sized array although I'm struggling to see the up-side to this extension)

Comment: Yes, it will work. But arr[128] will occupy space for 128 elements, but i actually used only 2. I might use 5 or 7 or 10, so i there any other approach to avoid taking up space for so many unused array elements. I read somewhere using malloc or something.

Comment: @MattMcNabb It totally blew my mind that `gcc` accepted it without warning: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -o bin/arrayval arrayval.c` Try it.

Comment: @user3388005 you can change the define to any number you like as long as it is greater than the number of digits entered. It was just an example.

Comment: @user3388005 take a look at the second version I posted. It will dynamically allocate only as much memory to `arr` as required to hold each digit in `n`.

Comment: Use `-pedantic` to get standard-compliance (or at least, as close as gcc tries to get)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int number, numberCount, tmp, count;

    printf("Please enter a number:\n>");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    tmp = number;

    for(numberCount = 0; tmp > 0; numberCount++)
        tmp /= 10;

    int numbers[numberCount];

    for(count = (numberCount-1); number > 0; count--) {
        numbers[count] = number % 10;
        number /= 10;   
    }

    for(count = 0; count < numberCount; count++)
        printf("%d digit is: %d\n", count+1, numbers[count]);


    return 0;

}
```

Input:

```
45
```

Output:

```
1 digit is: 4
2 digit is: 5
```

Comment: Thanks, but as i already mentioned this is just a section of my code. I want to put values 4 and 5 in array, so i need inprovement in my code, not a totally different new code. Hope you understand. :)

Comment: @user3388005 you have the values 4 and 5 in the array numbers! And if still can't use it, maybe you can use or see the concept :D

Comment: But you used forloop 2 times, but i used whileloop 1 time. I dont want to increase time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write more integers to your array than you have allocated space for. This code here:

```
while(n1>0)
{
    tmp=n1%10;
    arr[in]=tmp; // You initialize the array space to in, which is ambiguous. 
    len++;
    n1=n1/10;
    in++; // You increment the array after already initializing space which you can't do in this manner.

}
```

If you wish to accomplish in expanding your array based on the number of inputs from the user which is also ambiguous - you might think about using dynamic memory.

Comment: ok, actually i am PERL coder basically and trying to switch to C. In PERL, array handling is quite easy. Can you provide example of using dynamic memory. Any link or tutorial.

Comment: As you may already know, you can use @DavidC.Rankins response to understand how to use calloc for your particular situation. You can also find more material online here - [Dynamic Memory]http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-dynamic-memory-allocation

This will help you understand how to increase the size of your 'array' to benefit the amount of storage needed to hold your integer data types.